# Need add custom path of fonts in angular cli

Tags: angular

I have some custom font files has to download from CDN. I am able to import fro CDN in my styles.css but it is checking in assets/fonts for those font files.
Using this import

```
@import url(https://custom-fonts.com/custom-regular.ttf);
```

But at the same time getting an 404 error in console with like below.

```
http://localhost:4200/assets/fonts/custom-regular.ttf
```

How to change the config to use from CDN instead of assests/fonts folder?
Can anyone help me on this?

Comment: is this the url of CDN ? `https://custom-fonts.com/custom-regular.ttf` ? its not opening.

Comment: i tried the same by importing a font from google fonts in styles.css - `@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Spirax');` and i am able to use that. Please check if the URL you provided is correct

Comment: Thats the dummy link. But i need to change the path of that to CDN path where i have some variable like custom-font-path as per the library documentation. So, i am trying like $custom-font-path: "<Path to CDN>" but its not working still points to assets/fonts.

Answer (score -3):

You can change this setting from angular-cli.json or angulr.json file.

[image: assets array will contain the configuration.]

Comment: can you please elaborate on what you are trying to say as nothing is clear from your single statement and the SS you attached. Which setting to change? I dint change any setting in my angular app but still when i include custom font from a CDN in my styles.css and its working fine.

Comment: Please find my comment above.